# Nant nested if condition

Tags: nant

I am trying to do certain things when certain conditions are met, but it seems that somewhere my syntax is wrong. I need to have three `if` conditions to do one thing, but I'm not sure how to put in one of the `if` statements.

```
 <if test="${build.MoniXXXtor == 'true'} or test="${build.XXX== 'true'}" or   test="${build.yyy== 'true'}"> 
   <property name="solutionFile" value="${svn.Lib.path}"/>
   <property name="LocalPath" value="${Local.Lib.path}"/>
   <call target="getLatest" if="${source.getLatest == 'true'}"/>  
</if>
```

It seems the syntax for the `OR` condition above is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/tasks/if.html), you should use only one equals sign ( = instead of ==), e.g:

```
<if test="${build.configuration='release'}">
    <echo>Build release configuration</echo>
</if>
```

Comment: How do you specify one more if condition in same line.

Comment: How do you specify one more condition??

Comment: @user1248327: Have you clicked the link? Have a look at the second example.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that build.MoniXXXtor, build.XXX, and build.yyy are boolean properties the code is simply:

```
<if test="${build.MoniXXXtor or build.XXX or build.yyy}">
```

If they are string properties, they need to be converted to booleans:

```
<if test="${convert::to-boolean(build.MoniXXXtor) or 
            convert::to-boolean(build.XXX) or 
            convert::to-boolean(build.yyy)}">
```